# Como faço para adicionar valores em um vetor?

Tags: java, netbeans, array

Bem...eu sei adicionar valores em um vetor.
Na verdade não é bem isso.
Estou aprendendo java a pouco tempo e comecei a trabalhar com netbeans. O professor pediu uma atividade para criarmos um cadastro de matrícula para alunos.

Até agora o código ficou dessa forma:

Uma classe Aluno:

```
public class Aluno {
    
    private int matricula;
    private String nome;
    private int RG;
    private int CPF;
    private int fone;
    private int celular;
    private String rua;
    private int numero;
    private String bairro;
    private String cidade;

    /**
     * @return the matricula
     */
    public int getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    /**
     * @param matricula the matricula to set
     */
    public void setMatricula(int matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nome
     */
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    /**
     * @param nome the nome to set
     */
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    /**
     * @return the RG
     */
    public int getRG() {
        return RG;
    }

    /**
     * @param RG the RG to set
     */
    public void setRG(int RG) {
        this.RG = RG;
    }

    /**
     * @return the CPF
     */
    public int getCPF() {
        return CPF;
    }

    /**
     * @param CPF the CPF to set
     */
    public void setCPF(int CPF) {
        this.CPF = CPF;
    }

    /**
     * @return the fone
     */
    public int getFone() {
        return fone;
    }

    /**
     * @param fone the fone to set
     */
    public void setFone(int fone) {
        this.fone = fone;
    }

    /**
     * @return the celular
     */
    public int getCelular() {
        return celular;
    }

    /**
     * @param celular the celular to set
     */
    public void setCelular(int celular) {
        this.celular = celular;
    }

    /**
     * @return the rua
     */
    public String getRua() {
        return rua;
    }

    /**
     * @param rua the rua to set
     */
    public void setRua(String rua) {
        this.rua = rua;
    }

    /**
     * @return the numero
     */
    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    /**
     * @param numero the numero to set
     */
    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    /**
     * @return the bairro
     */
    public String getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    /**
     * @param bairro the bairro to set
     */
    public void setBairro(String bairro) {
        this.bairro = bairro;
    }

    /**
     * @return the cidade
     */
    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    /**
     * @param cidade the cidade to set
     */
    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }
    
}
```

E o código no jNewFrame ficou dessa forma:

```
public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        a = new Aluno[40];
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField8 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField9 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField10 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton10 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setAutoRequestFocus(false);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 12)); // NOI18N

        jLabel1.setText("MATRICULA");

        jLabel2.setText("NOME");

        jLabel3.setText("RG");

        jLabel4.setText("CPF");

        jLabel5.setText("CELULAR");

        jLabel6.setText("FONE");

        jLabel7.setText("NÚMERO");

        jLabel8.setText("RUA");

        jLabel9.setText("BAIRRO");

        jLabel10.setText("CIDADE");

        jButton1.setText("|<");

        jButton2.setText("<<");

        jButton3.setText(">>");

        jButton4.setText(">|");

        jButton5.setText("NOVO");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton6.setText("EDITAR");

        jButton7.setText("SALVAR");
        jButton7.setToolTipText("");
        jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton8.setText("CANCELAR");

        jButton9.setText("EXCLUIR");

        jButton10.setText("SAIR");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel8)
                                            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 110, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                            .addComponent(jTextField5))
                                        .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addComponent(jLabel9))
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel10)))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jButton1)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton2)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton3)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton4))
                            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton6))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jButton7))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jButton8))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jButton9))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel10)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel9))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addComponent(jButton2)
                            .addComponent(jButton3)
                            .addComponent(jButton4)))
                    .addComponent(jButton10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                .addContainerGap(38, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jButton5.setEnabled(false);
        jButton6.setEnabled(false);
        jButton9.setEnabled(false);
    }                                        

    private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        
        a[cont].setMatricula(Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()));
        a[cont].setNome(jTextField2.getText());
        a[cont].setRG(Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText()));
        a[cont].setCPF(Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText()));
        a[cont].setFone(Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText()));
        a[cont].setCelular(Integer.parseInt(jTextField6.getText()));
        a[cont].setRua(jTextField7.getText());
        a[cont].setNumero(Integer.parseInt(jTextField8.getText()));
        a[cont].setBairro(jTextField9.getText());
        a[cont].setCidade(jTextField10.getText());
        
        
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField10;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField8;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField9;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Acontece que ao clicar no botão salvar (jButton7) ele deve setar os valores de cada textfield para sua variável respectiva (ex.: Campo Nome -> setar para String Nome), fazendo isso para todos os valores no textfield e armazenar essas informações em um vetor (vetor a).

Eu não consegui fazer e espero que tenham compreendido e possam me ajudar a resolver esse problema.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode colocar assim:

```
jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
         Aluno aluno = new Aluno();//cria uma instancia do objeto aluno
         //seta os valoes pegando dos campos do seu formulario
         aluno.setNome(jTextField1.getText());//campo com o nome 
         //....etc vai preenchendo todas as propriedades

         //adiciona o objeto aluno na list
         a.[indiceQueVoceVaiUsar] = aluno;
     }
});
```

Ai voce vai ter so que controlar os indices do vetor.

Veja se te ajuda.